# Prevent Opera form caching mp3

Tags: php, caching, opera

again i try to prevent form caching mp3 files form my site. I use flash player, all files are outside public html i use this script to access to files

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'] . '.mp3';
 $fileDir = '/path/outside/public_html/';

if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
{
    ob_start();

    $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);

    echo $contents;

    $buffer = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_flush();

    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1980 00:00:00 GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, precheck=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');

    echo $buffer;

} ?>
```

I'm php noob so this script is probably buggy, but it's work... Almost, i have problem to prevent file cache in Opera - it still cache mp3 files. I saw some solution: when i play files from site, file was downloaded to cache but after full download file was automaticly delete. There is no time to copy this file. So my question is: ho do this ? Is this possible with php?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by server itself, to prevent file caching try to add some extra parameter to file name like:

```
$file = $_GET['file'] . '.mp3?' . time();
```

Comment: Thank you but this not work. I even don't get any error, just nothing happen.

Comment: This needs to be done for the URL when it's loaded in the browser, not here when the code has received the request and is about to look up the file..

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? Caching has several benefits: the end-user gets a better and faster experience, your server saves work and runs faster, you don't have to pay for so much bandwith, it saves the world's electricity and reduces network congestion.. So WHY do you need to break that?